# MSO retag request: [beta-phase] and [beta-sites]

Tags: support, retag-request, meta

There seems to be little *de facto* difference between MSO's [beta-phase](/questions/tagged/beta-phase) and [beta-sites](/questions/tagged/beta-sites) tags.

I suppose that in theory [beta-phase](/questions/tagged/beta-phase) might be more geared to the Area 51 site-launching process while [beta-sites](/questions/tagged/beta-sites) might have more to do with the beta sites themselves, that's a subtle and unnecessary distinction (and IMHO it isn't clearly represented in existing questions, and certainly not in the tag wikis).

Can these tags by synonymized or merged?